# Exchange 2013 API - Get Room Properties

Tags: c#, api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the room details from Exchange using EWS API.

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Exchange-2013-Get-a-room-0eada812/sourcecode?fileId=59837&pathId=28112893) is the example given for getting room list.

So as per the code I am trying to get the room details like location, city, state etc., but with code example's code block, I am only getting `Id, MailboxType, Name & RoutingType`.

Code snippet I have tried:

```
// Initialize service object here

EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.GetRoomLists();
foreach (EmailAddress address in myRoomLists)
{
     EmailAddress myRoomList = address.Address;
     Console.WriteLine("Email Address: {0}", address.Address);
}
```

Really appreciate if some can help me in getting the room property (Location, City, State etc.) with Exchange API in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RoomList operation will only return the EmailAddresses of the Room Mailboxes in the list. To get further information on these you will need to use an operation like ResolveName and return the ContactInformation eg

```
        EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.GetRoomLists();
        foreach (EmailAddress address in myRoomLists)
        {
            EmailAddress myRoomList = address.Address;
            PropertySet AllProps = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
            NameResolutionCollection ncCol = service.ResolveName(address.Address, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly, true, AllProps);
            foreach (NameResolution nr in ncCol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(nr.Contact.DisplayName);
                Console.WriteLine(nr.Contact.Notes);
            }
        }
```

Room Capacity is not a property that is exposed by EWS so you need to use a workaround to get it https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9eef45a5-dd1d-4912-9beb-bded7b40cb9e/ews-managed-api-using-c?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks for the reply Glen, Your code is giving me the properties of email address but I am not getting the some of the properties like `capacity`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: capacity is not a property that is exposed by EWS so you need to use a workaround to get it https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9eef45a5-dd1d-4912-9beb-bded7b40cb9e/ews-managed-api-using-c?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: I really appreciate your help Glen. Can you please update your answer with above comment in it, so that it can be clearly set as an answer.